# Disable and enable buttons using variables

Tags: c#, wpf, mvvm

I have a button that will be enabled or disabled with the use of a bool, I am using MVVM:

Button:

```
<Button x:Name="backButton" Content="Back" Command="{Binding BackCommand}" 
IsEnabled="{Binding Path=BackBool, Mode=OneWay, UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged}"/>
```

The bool:

```
    public bool BackBool
    {
        get { return isBackEnabled; }
        set
        {
            this.RaisePropertyChangedEvent("isBackEnabled");
            isBackEnabled = value;
            this.RaisePropertyChangedEvent("isBackEnabled");
        }
    }
```

I've added the bool to the variable watch and it updates correctly changing to true when the buttons should be enabled.

However the Buttons them selves do not update and always stay disabled.

Am I missing something?

Comment: if you want to Raise *Property* Changed, pass *property* name as parameter: `this.RaisePropertyChangedEvent("BackBool")`. Btw, commands (ICommand) have CanExecute method, if Button.Command is bound,  Button.IsEnabled is set based on return value of CanExecute

Comment: You shouldn't fire `PropertyChanged` event before backing field is updated. At this point you can fire `PropertyChanging` event of the [`INotifyPropertyChanging`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/library/system.componentmodel.inotifypropertychanging(v=vs.110).aspx) interface.

Comment: Down votes explained please

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Modified version of your code

Button:

```
<Button x:Name="backButton" Content="Back" Command="{Binding BackCommand}" 
IsEnabled="{Binding Path=BackBool, Mode=OneWay}"/>
```

The bool:

```
public bool BackBool
{
    get { return isBackEnabled; }
    set
    {
        isBackEnabled = value;
        this.RaisePropertyChangedEvent("BackBool");
    }
}
```

Answer (score 4):

Raise `PropertyChanged` with the name of the property whose value changed. You gave the `Binding` in the XAML exactly one applicable piece of information: The string "BackBool".

```
public bool BackBool
{
    get { return isBackEnabled; }
    set
    {
        isBackEnabled = value;
        this.RaisePropertyChangedEvent("BackBool");
    }
}
```

Also, omit the no-op flags from the binding. Never set an attribute on a binding until you've looked it up on MSDN and found out what it does. Saves a lot of scolding on Stack Overflow, and a lot of your own time testing changes that can't make any difference.

```
<Button 
    x:Name="backButton" 
    Content="Back" 
    Command="{Binding BackCommand}" 
    IsEnabled="{Binding Path=BackBool}"
    />
```

Comment: Small tip for all WPF developers: if you work with C# 6 or greater use `nameof` operator to pass property name when you fire `PropertyChanged`. If you decide to rename a property in the future it will be easier.